# Determine the unique vector x in the row space for A, for which Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the Vector $b = (9, -6, 3)^T$

$A =\begin{pmatrix}
         1 & 2 & 0 & 1\\
         -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
         1 & 0 & 2 &-1
        \end{pmatrix}$

I know that the row space is $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2& -1\end{pmatrix}$ , $ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1& 1\end{pmatrix}$

Not really sure how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way is to take some vector $\ x=( x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T$ and solve the system $\ Ax=b$ then you should get "template"  how your vector x should look like.

Comment: @CTSnake so then I get $ x_1 + 2 x_2 + x_4 = 9$

,
$-x_1-x_2-x_3 = -6$

,
$x_1 + 2x_3 - x_4 = 3$

Comment: You should get $\ x_1 + 2 x_2 + x_4 = 9\ and\ 

-x_1  - x_2 - x_3= -6\ and\ 

x_1 + 2 x_3 -x_4 = 3$

Comment: @CTSnake yeah that's what I got but I don't see how to solve it.

Comment: @CTSnake I solved it via using matrix row echelon form but now I have two free variables $x_3 and x_4$ but not sure how to proceed or use the basis for the row space.

Comment: If you use some values for $\ x_3,\ x_4 $ for example $\ x_3=1,\ x_4=1$ you will get a vector that is in row space

Comment: @CTSnake but when I do that and try $Ax$ I don't get $b$

Comment: After solving the system of equations you should get $\ x_1=3-2x_3+x_4, \ x_2=3+x_3-x_4$ and $\ x_3,x_4$ should be free

Comment: @CTSnake ah I accidentally added a minus sign.... Now I got it thanks!

Comment: The title of your question doesn’t match the answers that you and others are finding for this problem: there are free variables, so there is no *unique* solution. Is your title off or did you get $A$ or $b$ wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, this system of equations doesn't even a have a solution, for we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&2&0&1&6\\
-1&-1&-1&0&-6\\
1&0&2&-1&3
\end{array}
\right]
&\iff
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&2&0&1&6\\
0&1&-1&1&0\\
0&-2&2&-2&-3
\end{array}
\right]
\iff
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&2&0&1&6\\
0&1&-1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&-3
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Ah sorry, $ B$ is supposed to be $( 9, -6 , 3)$

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a vector $\ x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) $

For us to solve the given problem we need to solve the the system $\ Ax=b$

In our case$\ A=\pmatrix{1&2&0&1\\-1&-1&-1&0\\1&0&2&-1}$ and $\ b=\pmatrix{9\\-6\\3}$

$\ Ax=\pmatrix{1&2&0&1\\-1&-1&-1&0\\1&0&2&-1}*\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4}=\pmatrix{9\\-6\\3}$

After solving this system and taking $\ x_3,x_4$ as free variables you should get that$\ x=(3-2x_3+x_4,3+x_3-x_4,x_3,x_4)=(3,3,0,0)+x_3(-2,1,1,0)+x_4(1,-1.0,1)$

From this we conclude that our vector should be from vector space $\ (3,3,0,0)+span((-2,1,1,0),(1,-1.0,1))$